# How to modify "orderby" section of Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

Apologies for all the mistakes and poor terminology you are about to see. I am learning a lot still.

I am trying to create a command line application where the user selects certain options, and a LINQ query is created to match their selections.

From what I understand, I need to create delegate functions, fill the functions with the selections, then apply the functions in the Linq query. But it is very possible that I am on the wrong path entirely here.

I managed to correctly modify the "where" section of the code. However, the `orderby` section is not working properly.

Code runs fine, but isn't sorting. I imagine it is just ignoring my instructions as they are non-sensical.

As I was preparing this post, I saw a similar StackOverflow question which did provide me with a working solution:

I can create the search result without the `orderby` line, and then use:

```
searchResults = searchResults.Orderby(c => c.title);
```

However, I would like to learn if there is a way to do it using the method I was initially trying, as written below, such that I can put the full search in a single query rather than splitting off the `orderby` clause.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Book is a class that contains a title, author field
    Func<Book, bool> searchby; 
    string searchterm;
    Func<Book, string> sortby; //It is meant to output a TKey, not a string. But VisualStudio doesn't recognise TKey, and I can't figure out what a Tkey even is

    while (!endapp)
    {
        List<Book> bookList = New List<Book>(){...} //A non-empty list of book objects. 

        Console.WriteLine("Enter search term:");
        searchterm = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to search by A:title, B: author?");
        string response = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

        // I am trying to modify the "where" section of the LINQ query at the end based on the user response. 
        if (response == "a")
        {
            searchby = s => s.title.Contains(searchterm);
        }
        else if (response == "b")
        {
            searchby = s => s.author.Contains(searchterm);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Sort by A: title, B: author?");
        response = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

        // I am trying to sort the LINQ query at the end based on the user response. 
            
       if (response == "a")
       {
           sortby = s => s.title;
       }
       else if (response == "b")
       {
           sortby = s => s.author;
       }

       // LINQ query here
       var searchResults = from book in bookList
                           orderby sortby descending   // it is not sorting 
                           where searchby(book)
                           select book;

        foreach (Book book in searchResults)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(book.title);
        } 

        endapp = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you say it's meant to output a `TKey`? `TSomething` is usually a generic parameter name.

Comment: This is what is shown in documentation for the orderby filter:
**public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
            Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector);**


As a point of comparison, this is the one for where operator: 
**public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                                                  Func<TSource, bool> predicate);**


I saw the Func<TSource, bool> from where, compared that to Func<TSource, TKey> from orderby, and made a connection that TKey is the output.

Comment: Yes, so your `TSource` is `Book` and your `TKey` is `string`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Also, your solution was actually working correctly, I just didn't notice it properly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want the following:

```cs
var searchResults = from book in bookList
                    orderby sortby(book) descending 
                    where searchby(book)
                    select book;
```

At the  moment you're trying to sort by the func itself, not the value it returns. You can see that for `searchby` you passed `book` to it, but not `sortby`. This is why it isn't working. If you pass the `book` to `sortby`, it will sort based on the value returned by `sortby`.

P.S. I'd move the `orderby` after the `where` so that you don't sort items you then discard.

Comment: Thanks, that is very insightful.
Still doesn't work though. Is it likely because of Func<Book, string>?